# Javascript Arrays In IE 8 issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, internet-explorer-8, indexof

As per what I know, arrays in Javascript is nothing but the combination of methods and objects.

Now my task is to display the values of array (say `y_array`)

I have used `for(x in y_array)` and then displayed the value.

In mozilla and in IE its working fine, but in IE it displays the first element of array with index as `indexOf` and value is `indexOf(obj, from)` which i dont want.

I tried

```
if(x!='indexOf') {  display the array value ; }
```

It worked and things were fine but there is extensive use of arrays been displayed and I am looking for some permanent fix rather than this hardcoded one.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not the first mixing up arrays and objects. SO should contain a FAQ for this kind of questions ;)

Let's try to explain things:

An **array** is a row of values, which can be retrieved using their position in the row. The order of the array values is fixed (and may be reordered).

An **object** is a variable that contains named properties in the form of key-value pairs. The order of the key-value pairs belonging to an object is arbitrary.

An array looks like: `[ 'first', 'second', 'third', ..., 'nth' ]`
An object looks like: `{ first:'firstvalue', second:'secondvalue', ..., nth:'nthvalue' }`

The first element of an array is the element with index 0 (so the first position in the row has index value 0). You retrieve it using `myArray[0]`

An object is unordered, so it has no first element. You retrieve any element from it using `myObject.somekey` or `myObject['somekey']`.

For arrays you use a loop iterating through the numbered index until the end of the array is reached:

```
var i=0, len = myArray.length;
for ( i; i<len; i++ ) {
     //do something with >>> myArray[i] <<<
}
```

For objects you use a loop using the key and the `in` operator (making sure you are only retrieving user defined properties of the object with the `.hasOwnAttribute` method):

```
for ( var key in myObject ){
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     // do something with >>> myObject[key] <<<
  }
}
```

Basically, think of an array as a cupboard with drawers, each containing a value. An object can be imagined as a pile of boxes with stickers on the lid, describing the content of the box. Retrieving something from an object, you ask: *is there a box with sticker y in pile x and if so, what's in it*? Retrieving something from an array, you ask: *please give me the contents of drawer nr x*.

*Now as to your question*: the array you are retrieving values for with a `for..in` loop contains a user defined method, namely `indexOf`. Using the object style loop for it, the array is treated as object, and the `indexOf` key (with value like `function(){...}` I bet) is shown too. IE That's why it may be better to use a traditional for loop with a numeric index when iterating over arrays.

*Why is this only in IE*? In modern browsers `indexOf` is a native method of the `Array` prototype, and native methods are not shown (unless you loop through their prototype that is). IE < 9 doesn't have a native indexOf method for arrays. Somewhere in the scripting you use the method has been added to the Array prototype as a user defined extension.

Bottom line for your problem: don't use `for ... in` to loop through the values of an array.

Comment: FYI I had to use `myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)`. Not sure why but if youre having trouble with the above it might help

Comment: @cowls: well spotted. It was a mixup/typo, I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 6):

For arrays you should use this for loop:

```
var y_array = [1,2,3,4];
for (var i = 0; i < y_array.length; i++) {
  var value = y_array[i];
  // do what you want
  alert(i + ': ' + value);
}
```

For objects (objects are like associative arrays - property: value) use this loop:

```
var y_array = { prop_1 : "value a", prop_2: "value_2", prop_3: 333 }
for (var key in y_array) {
   var value = y_array[key];
   // do what you want
   alert(key + ': ' + value);
}
```

Comment: You have got me wrong Pavel, this is not what my question is. I am getting method indexOf as the first key of the array in IE which I want to skip and i tried matching the key as if(x!='indexOf') but thats hardcoded, I need some permanent solution as there are many such arrays

Comment: Do you want to skip all functions or the indexOf only?

Comment: I want to skip indexOf which is default the first element of array. Is there any function or method which does that thing or some good solution

Comment: You probably have typo in your question (_In mozilla and in IE its working fine, but in IE it displays ..._). Could you specify the problematic browser and put the code example to your question? I have test it with IE8, FF 4, Opera 11 nad Chrome 10 - and all seems behave the same.

Comment: @AbhishekSanghvi: @Pavel provided a correct solution for your problem (+1). Don't loop over an array with `for...in`. It can create problems, as you can see, and also loop over the functions defined on the array. Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in . Only use a normal `for` loop for array iteration (which is btw. also much faster).

Answer (score 0):

if there is no value in your json Object like jsobObj = {}. Then you got the indexOf prototype function in side the empty object in IE < 9. (with value like function(){...} I bet) is shown too.

Your can check a condition in side your for Loop. and skip that indexOf.

**if(key =='indexOf'){continue;}**

**E.g :**

```
var jsonObj = { key_1 : "value a", key_2: "value_2", key_3: 333 }
for (var key in y_array) {
if(key == 'indexOf'){continue;}           // check if the array contain indexOf 
   var value = y_array[key];
   // do what you want
   alert(key + ': ' + value);
}
```