# Accessing Array values dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have Array in this format.

```
rowData[0] = addRow(aa);        
rowData[1] = addRow(aaa);        
rowData[2] = addRow(aa);        
rowData[3] = addRow(aa);
```

addRow is a function which gets this value process.But i don't want to give the Array Index, instead i want to give rowData[i], then put in a loop and access the elements.

rowData holds the an object which addRow returns.

```
var data = [rowData];
var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
        data:data
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Array.push function to store the data:

```
rowData.push(addRow(aa));  
rowData.push(addRow(aaa));  
.
.
.
.
.
```

Another alternative is:

```
rowData[rowData.length] = addRow(aa);  
rowData[rowData.length] = addRow(aaa);  
.
.
.
.
.
```

Use the regular index based iterations to get the data:

```
for(var i=0; i< rowData.length; i++){
  var curItem = rowData[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++)
{
    rowData[i] = addRow(aa);
}
```

Comment: You've not been clear with what the difference is between `addRow(aa)` and `addRow(aaa)` and how that relates to the array index...

Answer (score 1):

did u mean this?

```
var rowData = {};
rowData[aa] = addRow(aa);
rowData[aaa] = addRow(aaa);
```

for loop access

```
for(var index in rowData){
  var data = rowData[index]
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A loop may not be feasible in your case. This may be an idea: you can rewrite the Array.push prototype method:

```
Array.prototype._push = Array.prototype.push;
Array.prototype.push = function(val){ this._push(val); return this;};
```

After which you can chain the push operations:

```
rowData.push(addRow(aa))
       .push(addRow(aaa))        
       .push(addRow(aa))        
       .push(addRow(aa));
```

But actually, it looks like you are mixing arrays with objects. [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659591/javascript-arrays-in-ie-8-issue/5660231#5660231) I formulated earlier on that subject.